# How to disable auto scroll to top on update of ajax event

Tags: ajax, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces, page-refresh

I want to stop the autoscroll to top, while doing a background page refresh.

for example, some one has scroll down and in between some update happened to that id, instead of scrooling to top it should remain at same position, and data should get updated.

Here is what I am using:

```
<p:poll interval="3"   
            listener="#{xyzBean.refresh}" update="#{xyzBean.refreshRequiredFlag ?'slim_panel' : ''}" async="true"/>

<p:dataTable id="slim_panel" cellpadding="5" value="#{xyzBean.records}" var="data" scrollRows="20" scrollable="true" liveScroll="true" scrollHeight="525">
            <p:column>
                <h:outputLink value="test">
                    <h:outputText escape="false" value="#{data.title}" />
                    <h:graphicImage value="test/23acfe2.jpg" height="20" width="50"/>
                </h:outputLink>
            </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Is there any way to preserve the state of dataTable irrespective of background data update?

Please help me out

Comment: ever figure this out?